# Firebase Realtime Database doesn't display in html

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Realtime Database and I'm trying to just display anything from it on an html page.  I can't seem to get it to do anything.  I have the permissions set to wide open, and I've followed a couple of tutorials, but still get nothing.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Firebase example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Firebase example</h1>
    <pre id='data'></pre>

<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-database.js"></script>

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "*",
    authDomain: "*",
    databaseURL: "*",
    projectId: "*",
    storageBucket: "*",
    messagingSenderId: "*",
    appId: "*",
    measurementId: "*"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  var ref = firebase.database().ref();
  ref.on("value", function(snapshot){
    output.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(snapshot.val(), null, 2);
  });

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I throw an alert in there, I can see that the code seems to fail at

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref();
```

But I have no idea why.  Could someone throw me bone and point me in the right direction? If I could just get to a point where it displays everything, I can figure it out from there, but I'm not making any progress at this point and could really use a little guidance with this.

Comment: When asking questions on Stack Overflow, it's expected that you show error messages that you might see in the browser console.  Code failures should always be accompanied by debugging information.

Comment: There is no error message.  The page is just blank in the browser.

Comment: Check all API calls for errors.  on() could fail and you'd never know.  Also include the results of any logging you do, so we can tell what you've tried to do to debug this.  It would also help if you explain what this code is supposed to do.  We can't see what `output` is.

Comment: I don't know what output is either. I'm just opening the html file in chrome.  I don't have any logging or debugging.  I have never done any javascript before and that's why I'm struggling with it.

Comment: If you don't know what you're code is supposed to do, Stack Overflow isn't the right place for you.  I suggest starting over with the official documentation and codelabs provided by Google.  If you're new to JavaScript, you should probably take time to learn that on its own before you add cloud hosted database services to that.  You should know JavaScript before starting with Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, remove this.  It's very old and not necessary:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.3.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

Second, you need to add a script include for the Realtime Database APIs.  Its version must match what you added for firebase-app.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

The best thing worth following is the documentation.  Stick with that alone, as old tutorials will give bad advice that conflicts with the correct information in the docs.

Comment: I made those changes, and now it appears to run through all of the code, but still doesn't display anything.  I've tried following the docs, but end up at the same endpoint - a blank browser window.  So I'm missing something somewhere along the line.